# Struggling with asymptotic analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing, asymptotics

I'd be glad for an explanation on the analysis of this exercise. Given these functions: $$f(n) = n^{1/2} \\ g(n) = n^{2/3}$$

Show that $f(n) = O(g(n))$, or $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$ and comment if $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$

**PS:** The exercise requires a mathematical demonstration of the answer.

Comment: In my solution, it is $\Theta(g(n))$ taking $n_0 = 1$  and $C = 1$

Comment: Did you finish this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Given $f(n) = n^{1/2}$ and $g(n) = n^{2/3}$, we can see that $f(n) = \O(g(n))$, because the function $g(n)$ grows faster than the function $f(n)$. We can demonstrate this writing the values for a series of inputs $0, 1, ...$ to $f(n)$ and $g(n)$:

$f(0) = 0$

$g(0) = 0$

$f(1) = 1$

$g(1) = 1$

$f(2) = 1.4$

$g(2) = 1.6$

$f(3) = 1.7$

$g(3) = 2$

Comment: What about $f(n) = O(g(n))$?

Comment: $f(n) = O(g(n))$ would not be true since the $f(n)$ grows faster. However, you can write $g(n) = O(f(n))$. Maybe it will help to visualize Big-O as '$\leq$' and Omega as the opposite.

Comment: I understand the order of growth. In fact, i must have said that the exercise requires the mathematical demonstration of the answer. That's where i'm struggling with.

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand what you are asking for then.

Comment: For instance, this is how i reached my answer: $n^{1/2} \leq C * n^{2/3} => \frac{n^{1/2}}{n^{2/3}} \leq C$

Comment: Sorry, i mistyped $f(n)$. It is $n^{1/2}$ instead of $n^2$

Comment: Ah, that obviously changes the outcome. In this case, it is true that $f(n) = O(g(n))$.

Comment: My demonstration is correct so?

Comment: In this case, yes.